# Lista encadeada imprime além do que é inserido

Tags: c, ponteiro, lista-encadeada

Eu tenho essa função

```
verticeobj* loadverticeObj(char *fname,verticeobj *vo){
    FILE *fp;
    int read;
    float x, y, z;

    char ch;
    fp=fopen(fname,"r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf("can't open file %s\n", fname);
        exit(1);
    }
        while(!(feof(fp)))
        {
            read=fscanf(fp,"%c",&ch);

            if(read==1&&ch=='v')
            {
                read=fscanf(fp,"%f %f %f",&x,&y,&z);

                vo =inserevertice(vo,x,y,z);
            }
            else
            {
                if(ch=='f')
                {
                    read=fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d %d",&x,&y,&z,&ch);
                }
            }
        }
    fclose(fp);

    return vo;
}
```

Que recebe a lista encadeada do tipo verticeobj e retorna a lista preenchida.Dentro da função, quando a condição é satisfeita, uma função de inserção é chamada passando novamente a lista para assim inserir os dados na lista.A função de inserção é:

```
verticeobj* inserevertice(verticeobj *lv, float x, float y, float z){
    verticeobj* novo = (verticeobj*)malloc(sizeof(verticeobj));
    novo->x = x;
    novo->y = y;
    novo->z = z;
    novo->prox = lv;
    lv = novo;

    return lv;
}
```

A questão é que na main quando eu chamo uma função de imprimir a lista, ela imprime os elementos desejados porem duas linhas a mais de lixo que não sei ao certo o que é.Dentro da função de inserção coloquei um printf para testar e ele imprime todos elementos corretamente. Desde já, obrigado

Comment: Quebrar a função `fscanf` ao ler `char`s misturados com `float`s e `int`s é muito fácil. Utilizar essa função é algo que tende a ser um tanto frágil pois ela só funciona bem quando os dados já estão devidamente formatados, produzindo coisas horrorosas quando dados fora do padrão esperado são encontrados. Como está o arquivo que você está lendo?

Comment: assim "v 25.0 15.0 25.0v 15.0 15.0 25.0f 1 2 3 4f 5 6 7 8" por exemplo

Comment: Há alguma quebra de linha nisso? Ou realmente temos `25.0f` com o `f` colado no `25.0`?

Comment: o arquivo tava com quebra de linha mas nao alterava o resultado final

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema era que eu não estava inicializando as listas encadeadas com NULL